# Simulate a where in scheme with defmac

Tags: macros, scheme

I'm actually faced to a problem in Scheme. And I just don't have any idea about how to solve it. It is pretty simple to understand and I guess kind of easy for any Scheme expert. I just have to simulate the where expression of haskell with the defmac function in scheme defining a macro "operation". For example, to execute a code like the following

```
> (operation (+ x y) 
   where ([x 1]
          [y (+ x 32)]))
34
```

I'm kind of familiar with the way to represent simple objects in scheme with macros (defmac) but now i'm really stuck with this problem.

Any help or idea would be really welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly you want to transform that code into something like

```
(let* ((x 1)
       (y (+ x 32))
  (+ x y))

(define-syntax operation
 (syntax-rules (where)
   ((operation expression where body)
    (let* body expression))))
```

Should do it, but only where "where" is right after the expression

Comment: Dude, you're only 13 minutes late. :-D

Comment: Drat, story of my life.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this should do the trick (using this defintion of [`defmac`](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~etanter/defmac.rkt)):

```
(defmac (operation expr
          where (binding ...))
        #:keywords where
  (let* (binding ...)
    expr))
```

It simply converts your `operation` form into the equivalent `let*`, so that your example would become:

```
(let* ((x 1)
       (y (+ x 32)))
  (+ x y))
```

Comment: but Haskell's `where` also allows `(operation (+ x y) where ([y (+ x 32)] [x 1] ))`. :) it's of course unclear whether this is intended by the OP to be solved or just ignored...

Comment: @Will In Haskell, that's easy to implement due to pervasive lazy evaluation. In Scheme, it's a little trickier. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys but i would more need something beginning like that. The thing is that i have some exigence from my teacher :
(defmac (val <ope> where (<var> <expr>) ...)
 #keywords: val where
 (let ((val-expr  <expr>) ...)
  (

Comment: @user2480503 `defmac` is not a standard Scheme macro, so I had to hunt around for it. The version I found was [here](http://tmp.barzilay.org/defmac.ss), and I've reformulated the macro to use that version.

Comment: @user2480503 I've found a different version, which is probably the version you're using: http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~etanter/defmac.rkt